# java logback: can i attach a custom function whenever a new log is written

Tags: java, red5, logback

I have a red5 application using java language and I use logback for logging.

whenever a log is written using logback i want to send it to the message to the user. is there a way to somehow attach to the logger class to be able to do another command when a log is being sent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Logback (but the idea applies to Log4J as well) decides to log given statement (based on logging levels and filters), he sends the `ILoggingEvent` to every so called *appender* attached to a given logger and its parents.

What you want is to implement your own appender (class implementing [Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/Appender.html) or preferably extending [AppenderBase](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/AppenderBase.html)) and add it to your `logback.xml` (simplified):

```
<root>
    <appender class="com.example.YourCustomAppender"/>
</root>
```

As you can see it is very simple, **but** before you write your own appender make sure that a similar appender doesn't already [exist](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your custom appender: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Just implement its `doAppend()` as you want. For example send message to user.
If you want to run "another command" you should use similar solution.